# how to return mysql query result using python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

the query result and expected output below.

```
+------+----------+
| YEAR | MAX_TEMP |
+------+----------+
| 1990 |      603 |
| 1991 |      605 |
+------+----------+
```

This is my code. In the output in just getting no of records (i.e 2). How can i make it to show the full table?

```
import MySQLdb

    conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","root","vkp")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    print ("Opened database successfully");

    def select():
        #database_conn()
        print ("inside select")
        a = cursor.execute("SELECT year(dt) AS YEAR, max(air_temp) AS MAX_TEMP from TEMP_DATA WHERE air_temp != 9999 AND (quality_at = '0' || quality_at = '1' || quality_at = '4' || quality_at = '5' || quality_at = '9') GROUP BY year(dt); SELECT year(dt) AS YEAR, max(air_temp) AS MAX_TEMP from MAX_TEMP9293 WHERE air_temp != 9999 AND (quality_at = '0' || quality_at = '1' || quality_at = '4' || quality_at = '5' || quality_at = '9') GROUP BY year(dt)")

        return a
        conn.commit()
        conn.close
    a = select()
    print (a)
```

Comment: That `return` looks like it's in the wrong spot here.

Comment: also not exactly sure what exactly is it returning for you?

Comment: edited my code.. im getting '2' as the output

Answer (score 2):

1. The indentation in your code is off; as written, your code won't compile (you might just have to correct the formatting in your question submission).
2. @aws_apprentice is correct.  You should include `fetchall` in your code.  I would write it like this:

   ```
   import MySQLdb

   conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","root","vkp")
   curs = conn.cursor()
   print ("Opened database successfully");

   def select():
       #database_conn()
       print ("inside select")
       curs.execute("""
           SELECT year(dt) AS YEAR, max(air_temp) AS MAX_TEMP 
           FROM TEMP_DATA 
           WHERE air_temp != 9999 
           AND (quality_at = '0' || quality_at = '1' || quality_at = '4' || quality_at = '5' || quality_at = '9') 
           GROUP BY year(dt); 
           SELECT year(dt) AS YEAR, max(air_temp) AS MAX_TEMP 
           FROM MAX_TEMP9293 
           WHERE air_temp != 9999 
           AND (quality_at = '0' || quality_at = '1' || quality_at = '4' || quality_at = '5' || quality_at = '9') 
           GROUP BY year(dt)
           """
           )

       result = curs.fetchall()

       return result

   a = select()
   conn.close()
   print(a)
   ```
3. I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think that MySQLdb will pretty-print the output as you indicated that you expect it, as this code is written.  There may be some method in the library that does this; might be worth some more research.  The code above will output a list of tuples (I think; untested) containing your data.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, This code is giving count of rows (2) rather than the actual row data. so i used index for getting the row data.                                                  max = cursor.fetchall()
        #printing max temp for years
        print(max[0])
        print(max[1])

Answer (score 1):

You're missing [fetchall](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html)

All you're doing is returning the number of results as opposed to the actual results themselves.

Change this:

```
a = cursor.execute("SELECT year(dt) AS YEAR, max(air_temp) AS MAX_TEMP from TEMP_DATA WHERE air_temp != 9999 AND (quality_at = '0' || quality_at = '1' || quality_at = '4' || quality_at = '5' || quality_at = '9') GROUP BY year(dt); SELECT year(dt) AS YEAR, max(air_temp) AS MAX_TEMP from MAX_TEMP9293 WHERE air_temp != 9999 AND (quality_at = '0' || quality_at = '1' || quality_at = '4' || quality_at = '5' || quality_at = '9') GROUP BY year(dt)")
```

To this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT year(dt) AS YEAR, max(air_temp) AS MAX_TEMP from TEMP_DATA WHERE air_temp != 9999 AND (quality_at = '0' || quality_at = '1' || quality_at = '4' || quality_at = '5' || quality_at = '9') GROUP BY year(dt); SELECT year(dt) AS YEAR, max(air_temp) AS MAX_TEMP from MAX_TEMP9293 WHERE air_temp != 9999 AND (quality_at = '0' || quality_at = '1' || quality_at = '4' || quality_at = '5' || quality_at = '9') GROUP BY year(dt)")

a = cursor.fetchall()
```

Also there's no point of having `commit` there. You're not modifying any data within the actual table in this function, which is what it is intended for.

Comment: I got this error                                                                             
     AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'fetchall'

Comment: Okay i guess need to do fetchall() on cursor. cusror.fetchall()

Comment: now im getting an object as output - <MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object at 0x7fcf38a04160>      : I tried converting it to string str(a) but still get the same output

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the output, this is the code is used.

```
databasename = 'vkp'
host = 'localhost'
user = 'root'
password = 'root'

#mysql connection
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host,user,password,databasename)
cursor = conn.cursor()

#defining sql select statements
print ("Opened database successfully");
sql = "SELECT year(dt) AS YEAR, max(air_temp) AS MAX_TEMP from TEMP_DATA WHERE air_temp != 9999 GROUP BY year(dt)"
sql1 = "SELECT year(dt) AS YEAR, max(air_temp) AS MAX_TEMP from MAX_TEMP9293 WHERE air_temp != 9999 GROUP BY year(dt)"
#list for storing sql queries
list = [sql,sql1]

#function for executing select statements 
def select():
    #iterating for loop
    for l in list:
        #executing query
        cursor.execute(l)
        max = cursor.fetchall()
        #printing max temp for years
        print(max[0])
        print(max[1])
```